# Is there a way to reassign Cmd+Shift+W shortcut in Spotify?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, spotify

I used to push Cmd+W to hide program window, but in Spotify Cmd+Shift+W will log you out, which is extremely annoying if I mistakenly press Shift. I tried to re-assign this button through Keyboard -> Shortcuts system settings menu, but for some reason it doesn't affect Spotify at all:

[image: Settings menu]
[image: Spotify]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en). Save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>SPOTIFY</appname>
    <equal>com.spotify.client</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <only>SPOTIFY</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::W, VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the KeyRemap4MacBook application, press the ReloadXML button, and tick the checkbox for the setting.

Comment: Thank you, do you know the reason why standard mac os shortcuts doesn't work in case of spotify?